# MongoDB Change Streams read changes from past

Tags: mongodb, changestream

I want to read changes in collections in my database. Now I choose between direct using of oplog and [Change Streams](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/#change-streams). I have few question about oplog Change Streams abilities

1. How to start read changes from very beginning of oplog using Change Streams?

Using oplog I can use `find()` on oplog collection with zero timestamp, but with Change Streams I can only pass `resumeAfter` and `startAfter` tokens. When I don't specified cursor options it start read changes from current moment, but in first run I need to start from very beginning.

2. What if my changes reader will lag behind oplog and  `resumeAfter` become outdate?

From [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/#resumeafter-for-change-streams):

> The oplog must have enough history to locate the operation associated with the token or the timestamp, if the timestamp is in the past.

How correctly process this situation?

3. Now I nead to read changes from single collection, but in the future I may need to read changes from several collections

With oplog I can just extend find filter and continue with with timestamp from state. Can I do same with Change Streams?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [startAtOperationTime option](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.watch/) to specify the starting time for a change stream. The starting time must be within the oplog window.

It should be possible to start a change stream from a point referenced by a token with that point being in the past, but you need to have obtained the token from the change stream previously. There is no API to create tokens from scratch on the client side.

Comment: Documentation say that I can check token with `db.getReplicationInfo()`, but it isn't reliably if oplog moving fast :(

Comment: Documentation says that where?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.watch/ 
`To check the time range of the oplog, see **rs.printReplicationInfo().**`

Comment: That refers to operation time, not resume tokens. What are you saying exactly?